# Expo-calender not working on production build (IOS)

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go, expo-calendar

I use the following code to get all calenders on the device:

```
const calendars = await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync(
      Calendar.EntityTypes.EVENT
);
```

On the IOS-Simulator, it returns the list of all device calenders as expected.
Using it in production on IOS, the following is returned.

[expo-calender-prod-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piILv.png)

Why are those two arrays of calenders different even if the same code is used?

I try to get all device calenders, it does not return all device calenders in production on IOS

"expo": "~49.0.8",
"expo-calendar": "^11.0.1",